# How can I move functions to a separate file in android studio?

Tags: java, android, function

How can I move functions to a separate file in android studio?

For example, if the following code is in my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   int VAR1;
   int VAR2;
   int VAR3
   ...
   protected void onStart() {
      ...
      VAR1 = 102;
      VAR2 = 105;
      VAR3 = add( VAR1, VAR2);
      ...

   }

   public void add ( int VAR1, int VAR2 ) {
      return VAR1 + VAR2;
   }
}
```

How can I have :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int VAR1;
    int VAR2;
    int VAR3
    ...
    protected void onStart() {
        ...
        VAR1 = 102;
        VAR2 = 105;
        VAR3 = add( VAR1, VAR2);
        ...

    }
}
```

functions.java

```
public void add ( int VAR1, int VAR2 ) {
    return VAR1 + VAR2;
}
```

Comment: Java basic. Create a new class with this function.

Comment: Copy and paste it to a new one.  How hard is that?

Answer (score 3):

In "Utils.java"

```
public static String getAnyData(){
   return "anyData";
}
```

called from MainActivity (e.g.)

```
Utils.getAnyData();
```

But keep in mind that only utility functions / methods should work like that. This is no [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)!

IntelliJ / AndroidStudio has a neat shortcut for this task.. see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/extract-method.html).

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps:

1. Click within the method body or name to be moved (do not highlight the function or its body)
2. Right Click->Refactor->Move
3. Shows a popup if there are no variables that have reference type. Click on "Yes". Studio will make your method static.
4. Again follow 1 and 2
5. Specify the target class in the dialog popup
6. Click Refactor

Answer (score 0):

Java is a fully object oriented language so you cant "store just functions in a file". You need to declare functions in classes. Either as static or non static.

So in your case you need to create a class in a new file and create the method inside it. If you declare the method as static you wont have to instantiate the class.

I suggest you to look for java basics.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the code you've in "How do I get this" part, but make your functions in that one `static`

```
public static void add ( int VAR1, int VAR2 ) {
    return VAR1 + VAR2;
}
```

This will allow other classes to use this function without a problem. You would call them with `Functions.add(...)`